# One Page Checkout Stuck on Step 5 Payment

Tags: onepage-checkout, payment, magento-1.6

I can't get past Step 5 Payment in my one page checkout system. I have checked the ID "checkout-payment-method-load" exists, and it does. No JS error. What could be wrong? Using Magento 1.6.

https://www.internationalplayground.com/

I also tried replacing line 81 of info.phtml to

```
review = new Review(’getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveOrder', array('form_key' => Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey())) ?>’, ‘getUrl('checkout/onepage/success') ?>’, $(’checkout-agreements’));
```

in exception.log

```
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_PaypalUk_Block_Link_Shortcut' in /home/internat/public_html/app/Mage.php:563
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(469): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
    #1 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(411): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('paypaluk/link_s...', Array)
    #2 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(446): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('paypaluk/link_s...', 'checkout.cart.m...')
    #3 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(238): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('paypaluk/link_s...', 'checkout.cart.m...')
    #4 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(204): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #5 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(209): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #6 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(345): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
    #7 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(270): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #8 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(149): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
    #9 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
    #10 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #11 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #12 /home/internat/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #13 /home/internat/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #14 /home/internat/public_html/index.php(82): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #15 {main}
```

Comment: We need more information. At step 5, after clicking to continue, the route `checkout/onepage/savePayment` does not give a response body (though it should). Have you turned on developer mode to see any error output? Or what about `exception.log`? What version of Magento are you using, and what extensions possibly related to checkout/payment do you have installed? Also, have you tried to enable additional payment methods and test those?

Comment: @RickBuczynski added more information.

Comment: Thanks. Now are you able to confirm that this exception is thrown out of the `checkout/onepage/savePayment` action? Or at least at the exact moment you click to continue? I'm trying to avoid a rabbit hole with that exception trace.

Comment: ... Notice that the trace you provided appears to be part of a cart page view. Also, when did this start happening, and what changed near that time?

Comment: Actually I think it happens when I click "Add to Cart" button on a product page...! or maybe when the cart page is loaded? @RickBuczynski

Comment: Right, see #s 8 and 10 of your exception trace, that would indicate the route of `checkout/cart/index` which is *not* the route in question here, `checkout/onepage/savePayment` -- unless you can get an error at the moment you click to continue from step 5 of the checkout, I don't think the missing PayPal block is your problem.

Comment: No, I don't get an error when I click continue from step 5. What could be the problem? @RickBuczynski

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24901/discussion-between-rick-buczynski-and-user2741060).

Comment: @RickBuczynski I found out which code was causing the problem, and asked a different question for that. Could you please take a look? I'd appreciate it. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71347/cannot-retrieve-payment-method-instance

Answer (score 1):

Error says that there should be block class `Mage_PaypalUk_Block_Link_Shortcut` which is called using block type `paypaluk/link_shortcut` but as per magento default 1.6  **this class does not exits in system**.

That's why it shows error. You need to remove it from layout file.

As per my concept block type should be `paypaluk/express_shortcut`.

Comment: but my magento is 1.6.

Comment: sorry , i have check it  on 1.6 but there are this class not exits.