# After Upgrading to 1.9.3.4 onepage checkout get suck to step 5 Payment Information

Tags: payment

I have upgraded my magento to 1.9.3.4 and I got stuck at Payment Information step. Selecting a payment method and clicking continue doest not load next step. I have only two Payment method 1. Cash on Delivery 2. Check. When I saw the exception log. It says exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_PaypalUk_Block_Link_Shortcut' in /app/Mage.php:595.
Below is the complete error log with stack trace:

```
2017-07-29T14:54:48+00:00 ERR (3): 
    exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_PaypalUk_Block_Link_Shortcut' in /mydomain/app/Mage.php:595
    Stack trace:
    #0 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
    #1 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('paypaluk/link_s...', Array)
    #2 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('paypaluk/link_s...', 'checkout.cart.m...')
    #3 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('paypaluk/link_s...', 'checkout.cart.m...')
    #4 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #5 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
    #6 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
    #7 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
    #8 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(194): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
    #9 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->indexAction()
    #10 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
    #11 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #12 /mydomain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #13 /mydomain/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #14 /mydomain/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #15 {main}
```

I have added the formkey to form of each checkout step files of my theme. Also checked the opcheckout.js

if (elements[i].name=='payment[method]' || elements[i].name == 'form_key') {is available at opcheckout.js

Kindly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Search the whole project and replace

> paypaluk/link_shortcut

with

> paypaluk/express_shortcut

[Identical question answered here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71259/one-page-checkout-stuck-on-step-5-payment)

Comment: I search in my app folder, but there is no such.

Comment: Could it be cached?

Comment: @javedahmed Have you tried the whole project, not just app? As zivorad said the answer here is your answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71265/41603

Comment: @Zivorad there is no cache. i deleted the var/cache. but it is still

Comment: @tim. i search in app as all the code are in app thats why and.. yes i saw that link also , there is no solution provided in it.